# Password to Confirm then Continue

Tags: java, swing, jframe, textfield, indexoutofboundsexception

**EDIT :** iam using Netbeans 8.0.1

I've been days trying to search for a solution I tried jdialog and other things and couldn't help I hope you guys help me. 
I noticed that after the user set the passwords and I set the `fechadesalida = null`, in my Database MySQL it will save all the text field as empty spaces.

When the java application starts `accion = "insertar";`
First of all I fill the TextFields, then I click this button

```
     private void btnGuardarSalidaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 

    if (cboCamion.getSelectedItem() != null) {
        if (cboChofer.getSelectedItem() != null) {
            if (T_SalidaKm.getText().trim().length() != 0) {
                if (T_FechaSalida.getText().trim().length() != 0) {
                    ChoferLogin Chofer = new ChoferLogin();
                    Chofer.a = ((String) cboChofer.getSelectedItem());
                    Chofer.setVisible(true);
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Inserte la Fecha");
                }
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Seleccione el Km Salida");
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Seleccione el Chofer");
        }
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Seleccione el Camion");
    }

}
```

then another class jframe popup , here the user insert his password then the bottun is cicked

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    ChoferLog();


}
```

this is the method ChoferLog();
        public void ChoferLog() {

```
    String sql4 = " Select * from choferes where chofer=? and Password=?";

    try {
        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql4);
        pst.setString(1, a);
        pst.setString(2, T_Password.getText());

        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Confirmado");
            viajes.GuardarSalida();
            this.dispose();

        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La Contrasena es incorrecto");
        }

    } catch (SQLException | HeadlessException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error" + e);
    }

    dispose();
}
```

this is the method GuadarSalida(); from class Viajes

```
     void GuardarSalida() {
    switch (accion) {
        case "insertar":
            sql = "insert into viajes(camion,chofer,kmsalida,acompanhante,"
                    + "viatico,destino,cargadediesel,litros,fechadesalida,"
                    + "bascula,peaje)"
                    + " values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ";
            break;
        case "modificar":
            sql = "Update viajes set "
                    + "camion= ?,"
                    + "chofer= ?,"
                    + "kmsalida= ?,"
                    + "acompanhante= ?,"
                    + "viatico= ?,"
                    + "destino= ?,"
                    + "cargadediesel= ?,"
                    + "litros= ?,"
                    + "fechadesalida= ? ,"
                    + "bascula= ?,"
                    + "peaje= ? "
                    + " where idviajes = " + id;
            break;
    }
    sql = "insert into viajes(camion,chofer,kmsalida,acompanhante,"
            + "viatico,destino,cargadediesel,litros,fechadesalida,"
            + "bascula,peaje)"
            + " values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ";

    try {

        day = T_FechaSalida.getText().substring(0, 2);
        month = T_FechaSalida.getText().substring(3, 5);
        year = T_FechaSalida.getText().substring(6);
        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, (String) cboCamion.getSelectedItem());
        pst.setString(2, (String) cboChofer.getSelectedItem());
        pst.setString(3, T_SalidaKm.getText());
        pst.setString(4, (String) cboAcompanhante.getSelectedItem());
        pst.setString(5, T_Viatico.getText());
        pst.setString(6, T_Destino.getText());
        pst.setString(7, T_CargadeDiesel.getText());

        if (T_CantDiesel.getText().isEmpty()) {
            pst.setString(8, null);
        } else {
            pst.setString(8, T_CantDiesel.getText());
        }

        pst.setString(9, year + "-" + month + "_" + day);
        pst.setString(10, T_Bascula.getText());
        pst.setString(11, T_Peaje.getText());
        pst.executeUpdate();

        TablaDeEspera();
        LimpiarSalida();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se Cargo Con Exito !", "Guardar", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Se Cargo Los Datos " + ex);
    }

}
```

and I get this problem, please help I've been days searching and couldn't find solution

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 2
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1950) at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1950)
at Viaje.Viajes.GuardarSalida(Viajes.java:353)
at Viaje.ChoferLogin.ChoferLog(ChoferLogin.java:61)
at Viaje.ChoferLogin.jButton1ActionPerformed(ChoferLogin.java:197)
at Viaje.ChoferLogin.access$300(ChoferLogin.java:22)
at Viaje.ChoferLogin$3.actionPerformed(ChoferLogin.java:116)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Words typed in all lower case are hard to read, like trying to listen to someone who is mumbling.  Please use an upper case letter at the start of sentences, for the word I, and proper names like `ArrayList` or Oracle.

Comment: line 353 is         day = T_FechaSalida.getText().substring(0, 2);